# Remove x86_64 package from Realm

Tags: android, realm

I'm working with AS and I don't need the x86_64 package in realm. The x86_64 package cause some problems with other libs. How to remove the package?

[image]

Comment: What is AS? Also, maybe consider posting your issue WITH x86_64 instead of trying to remove it

Answer (score 5):

`abiFilters` will be a good solution. The method will limit the abi and only add the specified abi when building the apk.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
// ...
}
```

This means only those specified arch-folders will be used and the rest can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can remove any of the architecture folders, but keep in mind, that means the library in question (this case it's realm) will not work on those architectures that you remove.

To be frank, you can just simply remove it, but as I mentioned above, that is no good.

You can include/exclude different architectures from your build by a technique called `splitting`:

```
android {
    // Rest of Gradle file
        splits {
            abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64_v8a', 'mips', 'x86'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
}

//Ensures architecture specific APKs have a higher version code
//(otherwise an x86 build would end up using the arm build, which x86 devices can run)
ext.versionCodes = [armeabi:1, 'armeabi-v7a':2, 'arm64-v8a':3, 'mips':4, x86:5]

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // assign different version code for each output
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        int abiVersionCode = project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)) ?: 0
        output.versionCodeOverride = (abiVersionCode * 10000) + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much ,what you said is a solution .but this will build many apks for different devices. now my way is using abiFilters to limit the abi.  ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }